# Huge performance difference for the same SQL query with different parameter

Tags: postgresql, indexing

I'm trying to understand why my queries are having huge performance difference in my case.

I have this table has columns: timestamp, ticker, open, high, low, close, volume, exchange.
The database is Postgres 9.6.

The table is around 300 million rows.

I've built the following index:

- unique index on (timestamp, ticker, exchange),
- index on (ticker),
- index on (exchange).

My query is as follows

```
SELECT MAX(timestamp) FROM table WHERE ticker='ticker1' AND exchange='exchange1';
```

But for different values for tickers, I'm having huge query time difference, ranging from 300ms to 7mins.

I'm trying to understand what is causing this and if I can improve it in any ways.

More information:

```
create table ohlcv (
    timestamp bigint,
    ticker varchar(20),
    open double precision,
    high double precision,
    low double precision,
    close double precision,
    volume double precision,
    exchange varchar(20),
    constraint ohlcv_timestamp_ticker_exchange_key
        unique (timestamp, ticker, exchange)
);

create index ohlcv_exchange_index on ohlcv (exchange);
create index ohlcv_ticker_index on ohlcv (ticker);
```

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question and add both [execution plans](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/using-explain.html) (the slow and the fast) generated using **`explain (analyze, buffers, format text)`** (_not_ just a "simple" explain) as  [formatted text](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) and make sure you prevent the indention of the plan. Paste the text, then put `\`\`\`` on the line before the plan and on a line after the plan. Please also include complete `create index` statements for all indexes as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need this index:

```
CREATE INDEX ON "table" (ticker, exchange, timestamp);
```

It can find the rows satisfying the `WHERE` condition quickly, and then the `max` can be found very quickly.

Since you already have a unique constraint with these columns (but in the wrong order), you can drop and re-create the constraint. That will have the same effect, since it is backed by an index.

Comment: For postgres, when creating constraint, an unique index is created, so I already have an unique index on (timestamp, ticker, exchange). In this case will your solution help? Also postgres has the ability to use multiple indexes at the same time, I believe: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/indexes-unique.html, https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/indexes-bitmap-scans.html